# out of memory when saving a large string data into a text file using open() function

Tags: python, file, memory, background, save

I tried to save a large string data into a text file using following code.

```py
@api.route("/upload/{project_name}/files")
async def receive_files(req, resp, *, project_name):

    @api.background.task
    def save_files(uploaded_data, project_name):

        filename = uploaded_data['filename']
        filedata = uploaded_data['data']


        with open(f"data/{project_name}/{filename}", "w", encoding="utf-8", newline="") as f:
            f.write(str(data))
            print('successfully saved', filename)

    data = await req.media()
    save_files(data, project_name)
    resp.media = {'success': True}
```

When I send a large file like 600MB csv file to this function, this process failed due to out of memory. It works with files less than 300MB. Is there any way I can optimize this function?? Thank you in advance.

I am using [python-responder](https://responder.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/) and a laptop with 16GB RAM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to pass the right media format, files for responder-python.

```py
data = await req.media(format='files')
```